# Desde una tabla, debo eliminar una columna siempre que no exista otra columna asociada en otra tabla

Tags: sql

Tengo una tabla 'Clientes' y una tabla 'Proyectos'. Y los proyectos siempre están asociados a un cliente mediante una llave foránea. Lo que necesito, es eliminar a un cliente siempre que no exista un proyecto asociado. Cómo realizo esto con un Query de SQL?

Teóricamente, debo consultar la tabla 'Proyectos' y si no encuentra registros asociados al ID del cliente, el cliente se puede eliminar. Pero no sé cómo escribir esto en un Query.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. También sería interesante que mirases, [¿cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). De la pregunta no se entiende si estás buscando una consulta para hacer un delete, o una consulta con Inner Join.

Comment: Crea las tablas, mete algún dato de ejemplo e intenta la query. Hasta que no lo hayas intentado, no podemos ayudarte...

Comment: `DELETE FROM clientes WHERE cliente_id not in (SELECT cliente_id FROM proyectos)`

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo de dos formas:

1. Valiéndote de la cláusula `not exists` para evaluar, por cada cliente, la no existencia de proyectos. Para lograrlo, basta con que la sub-consulta devuelva un resultado cualquiera para que el `not exists` devuelva `false` y con eso retener al cliente. Estoy asumiendo que el campo que relaciona las tablas se llama `idCliente` en ambas.

   ```
    delete 
      from Clientes
     where not exists (select 1 
                         from Proyectos
                        where Proyectos.idCliente = Clientes.idCliente)
   ```
2. Valiéndote de una cláusula `not in`. En este caso, tendríamos que obtener todos los `idCliente` que SI tienen proyectos, para luego eliminar a los que no se encuentren en ese conjunto de datos.

   ```
    delete
      from Clientes
     where idCliente not in (select idCliente
                               from Proyectos)
   ```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Aún no pruebo la segunda alternativa que me diste, pero la primera me funcionó perfecto.